# How can I show a message to IE6/IE7 browsers to upgrade to IE8 and have IE8 not show the IE7 warning?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I want to only allow users with IE8 (not IE6, IE7) or another browser to access my site when logged in.

I followed: http://code.google.com/p/ie6-upgrade-warning/
But I also wanted it to not allow IE7 users to use the main site when logged in (they can view public pages.)  The reason is that the main web application has a lot of JavaScript effects that will only work 100% in IE8 rendering mode (or any other browser aside from IE.)

The problem with modifying the ie6 upgrade warning to be ie7 is that it looked like IE8 displayed my webpage in an IE7 rendering mode and "lies" about being ie7 and triggers the IE7 stylesheet code.

So how can I force IE8 to always render my page in IE8 mode?

Comment: You really want to exclude around 40-50% of the world's users? Seriously?

Comment: You haven't specified which programming language you would like to do this with.

Comment: FYI: Current browser market-share - http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: If I hear any more complaints from people that I'm not including IE6 and IE7, I'm also going to exclude IE8!

Comment: There are plenty of apps that are meant for a limited audience. And in those cases you may be able to dictate the specific program and minimum version. Of course these cannot be called "web apps". I call them IE-apps, since IE is the "operating system" that they run on.

Comment: Sometimes you only need to allow the latest browsers for a targeted audience.

Comment: Why would anyone assume that the poster is excluding 50-60-99% percent of the world's internet users? People please refrain from vague and out of focus remarks. The poster never declares a target audience/market for his web app, it's unclear if it's a web site or perhaps an intranet app that couldn't care less of the world's addiction to bad/archaic software or even a school project. Lets not discuss browser market-share and whatever our opinion is. I dont know of a conclusive technique to do what you ask (maybe a combination of some of the following answers) so I will now shut up.

Comment: @MikeN: you should :D   make everyone use links instead!

Comment: @Yoooder: don't be ridiculous, everyone knows w3schools stats are MASSIVELY inaccurate of the web at large. WP is more accurate in this case: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

Comment: I stop supporting IE8 as soon as IE 10 was out and adding a warning for IE9 to upgrade. Unfortunately, there are still a lot of our users using Windows XP with IE8 (which is the maximum allowed for XP). We'll have to educate our users to upgrade IE instead of complaining and adding all kind of messages! I don't lose any occasion to say: "Please upgrade your browser!"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use this tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Comment: Yes, that will correctly force IE8 to render his site in IE8 mode, and cause JavaScript and Conditional Comments to report IE8. On the server side, checking for "Trident 4.0" in the user-agent header is also valid.

Often we suggest that folks use "IE=EmulateIE8" just to ensure that any Quirks mode pages aren't inadvertently forced into Standards mode, but this poster seems like a standards-junkie and isn't likely to be using Quirks Mode pages.

Answer (score 14):

Correction to AdamSane's example:

> `<!--[if lt IE 8]>
>   Special instructions for IE 7 or less here
>   <![endif]-->`

Comment: This won't work if the page is in Compatibility View mode.  In that mode, IE8 uses the IE7 version info for conditional comments.

Answer (score 11):

here is a good link that suggest some solution

http://garmahis.com/tools/ie6-update-warning/

personally i like fourth solution(http://www.browser-update.org/)

just a piece of cake

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would recommend users to upgrade IE for security reasons.  I would use a conditional comment to target browsers below IE8.

```
      <!--[if lt IE 8]>You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer.  For security reasons you should upgrade your browser. Please go to Windows Updates and install the latest version.<![endif]-->
```

This message should be unobtrusive but graceful.  You should also make the website usable for those that cannot upgrade their browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than try to force IE 8+ mode, I use a combination of conditional comments and a simple javascript check. The `document.documentMode` property was added to IE in version 8, so if it exists at all (regardless of value, though it HAS to be 7 with this code) it means we're in compatibility mode and should not show the warning:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <script>
        if (!document.documentMode) { //if documentMode exists, this is a later IE in compatibility mode
            showBadBrowserMessage();
        }
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is this cool script that works for all old browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var $buoop = {vs:{i:7,f:5,o:12,s:5,n:9}}; 
    $buoop.ol = window.onload; 
    window.onload=function(){ 
     try {if ($buoop.ol) $buoop.ol();}catch (e) {} 
     var e = document.createElement("script"); 
     e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
     e.setAttribute("src", "//browser-update.org/update.js"); 
     document.body.appendChild(e); 
    } 
</script>
```

Note: If the visitor ignores the advice, it won't appear again for some time.

More can be found: [here](http://browser-update.org/#install)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you've coded your (X)HTML, but IE8 should use standards mode (not IE7 mode) if you have a strict doctype like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

at the top of your HTML files.

[XHTML 1.0 Specs - Strictly Conforming Documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#strict)

Here's a good post about how different doctypes/etc affect IE8's rendering mode: [Understanding Compatibility Modes in Internet Explorer 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx)

Comment: Not exactly.  Anyone can trigger IE8's compatibility mode at anytime by clicking on the stupid broken page icon.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way would be to detect the user's browser User-Agent string and redirect them to a page asking them to upgrade (or download a different browser such as firefox or chrome) if they are using an old version of IE. You can see examples of the user agents of IE 7 and 8 on this [IE developer blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/01/09/the-internet-explorer-8-user-agent-string-updated-edition.aspx). Older versions of IE follow a similar pattern.

One thing you should not do, however, is assume that any user agent string not following a certain pattern is invalid. Just check for MSIE ([0-9]) and see if it's in range; if it's missing entirely, assume the browser is supported. If it's MSIE 7, then further check for the Trident marker indicating compatiblity mode (and, I suppose, ask the user to turn it off). This will allow for other, future upstart browsers to have a fighting chance at rendering your page without turning them away at the door :)

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned I'd suggest the best way to achieve this is to use conditional comments to include a stylesheet specific to all versions of IE earlier than 8:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]> Include CSS here <![endif]-->
```

The included CSS could set a warning to be visible or perhaps enable an overlay on the page which 'locks' users out. It might be a good idea to include some rules which hide important elements on the page which could otherwise confuse the user if they do not work as intended.

Your other option is to redirect the user to another page - I'm not a huge fan of redirects but if used with care they can be a suitable solution.

Have you considered **why** you're locking a large amount of users out of your site?
Maybe you should take the time to work out how to either gracefully degrade your JavaScript, or the other way around; 'progressively enhance' with JavaScript.

On the other hand, you might have control over the systems used by the organisation using your site in which case you're probably OK locking people out for using non-standard systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Conditional Comments

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: And do what, use CSS to hide all the elements on the page? CSS can't restrict access.

Comment: @AdamSane - These are just conditional comments - no need for the 'CSS' bit.
@Chad - It shouldn't need to restrict access - just make a warning visible and hide anything that could confuse the user. If the user can break something by not having JavaScript working/working correctly, then there's a problem with the application.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you can ask which browser have sent the request>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function detectBrowser()
{
var browser=navigator.appName;
var b_version=navigator.appVersion;
var version=parseFloat(b_version);
if (browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
  && (version>=8))
  {
  alert("Your browser is good enough!");
  }
  else
  {
  alert("It's time to upgrade your browser!");
  }
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: This won't work if the page is in Compatibility View mode.  In that mode, IE8 uses the IE7 version info for conditional comments and the JavaScript user-agent.

Answer (score 0):

Is this party over? ><

It is, but I think the information here can be updated a bit.

By today's standards, "today" being October 29 of 2013, you can use this meta tag to trigger the latest IE Browser and Document modes and trigger the installation of Google's Chrome Frame in older IEs:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

This allows you to server specific IE6/7 styles. Keep in mind that I'm saying 'styles' not 'style sheets', meaning: You'd only use a single CSS file and in it are all your IE6 and IE7 styles. This is to minimize HTTP requests... but that's a totally different conversation.

Anyway, with the above snippet there's no need for scripts or Conditional Comments.

**Note:** Google Chrome Frame will be retired in January 2014 - [more info here](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html).

Answer (score -2):

The very idea that you're "banning" IE 6 and 7 users from your website is ridiculous. A lot of people can't upgrade their browser or install another one because of work restrictions or because they don't know how. Barring these people from using your site will just cost you users in the long run.

Either fix your JavaScript, work around the problems or gracefully degrade so that the site will work well even if it's turned off.

EDIT: I posted some more information in a comment below which should really be in this post:

It's often possible to detect IE and work around it. Hell, you can even use conditional comments to load a different version of the JavaScript. Using a JS framework will abstract away the differences between browsers to a level you don't need to worry about. Or just grab [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) and stick that on the site - I hear it gets things working like you wouldn't believe.

Comment: It's hard to fix your JavaScript when you have to either neuter features or standards compliancy--IE loves to have its own interpretation of standard code, which often leaves you supporting IE or the rest.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure he's not barring them from the site, but telling them that if they're using IE6/7 they may as well not even try.  Warning your users that their incompatible client is not supported is good defensive coding.

Comment: It's often possible to detect IE and work around it. Hell, you can even use conditional comments to load a different version of the JavaScript. Using a JS framework will abstract away the differences between browsers to a level you don't need to worry about. Or just grab IE7.js (http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) and stick that on the site - I hear it gets things working like you wouldn't believe.

Comment: I agree with the idea of "banning" IE 6 and 7 users.  Of course I go a little further on one of our admin  sites.  We ban any non-current release browser version.  Which means anything less then IE8, Firefox 3.6, Safari 4.0.4, etc.  This is for security and performance reasons.  Thus far our clients haven't balked.

Comment: If he's like us, he might not be writing a public-facing website, but an intranet site which has a definitive policy on the unsupported nature of browsers less than version X