# Weird behaviour when setting PHP value inside javascript statement

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I have the below code in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 8') != -1) {
        <?php $ie8 = 1; ?>
        alert(<?=$ie8?>);
    }

</script>
```

Now this will correctly ONLY output the alert if the browser is IE8. All good there.

However, if I test the `$ie8` value after this has run, such as:

```
var_dump($ie8);
```

I always end up with the value of `int(1)` whether the browser is IE8 or not. I tested the value before the function is run to make sure it wasn't set elsewhere, but I as expected got a `NULL` output.

So my question is, how is this being set to `1` when it isn't even going into the javascript statement?

Comment: I dont understand. You are assigning 1 to `$ie8` after javascript checks for browser. How do you think PHP will know what Javascript returned!!

Comment: JS is clientside and PHP is serverside...

Comment: You should set the value in javascript, maybe on the input field, then pass that to php later on. Is there any reason to be getting the browser though? Also you can use php to get it http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php then pass it to javascript.

Comment: @Broncha Because it is inside a PHP script. I have no problems getting the values in PHP via my tests.

Comment: @Matt Obviously there is a reason otherwise I wouldn't be doing it lol

Comment: @Brett yea but what, there might be a better way. You can't expect one language to know what a different language is doing. It just doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Brett whatever you are doing, you are taking the wrong approach, think about it, PHP will never know what `if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 8') != -1)` returned. Check the source that is being generated and you will find out why it is not working.

Comment: @Broncha Yes, that's true. After reading hanky's answer below it made sense.

Comment: @Matt I am trying to output a message to IE8 users to upgrade or user another browser as there is a bug that only exists in IE8 (haven't tested anything lower).

Comment: @Brett there are few things you can do. http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822508/how-can-i-show-a-message-to-ie6-ie7-browsers-to-upgrade-to-ie8-and-have-ie8-not

Comment: @Marc thats what I am explaining.

Comment: @Brett and if IE7 or 6 doesn't work, then it won't matter. You already gave them a warning. There is no reason to do anything extra server side.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the link; and yeah, I'm not worried about IE6/7, so no big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When that file goes to PHP it doesnt care about your javascript logic. That php ie8 =1 will always get executed unless your 'if' is a PHP one and not JS.

It is just like if an off duty pilot is sitting in a plane as passenger. Do his logics impact the on duty pilot? No. When PHP is working then at that time JavaScript is Off duty and doesnt matter a cent to PHP Pilot

Comment: That makes more sense & explains why setting it to `2` in an `else` clause makes it equal to `2`.

Comment: Brett see the edit that might explain it a little more

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use Javascript and PHP as a single language, when one is server side and one is client side.

In PHP, `$ie8` will always be `1`.  It doesn't matter what kind of HTML or Javascript you throw at it because Javascript is executed by the client only, when they view the page, where as PHP is rendered by the server when it serves the page.

If you want to set a value in PHP based on a Javascript function, you will need to use AJAX which sends a request from the client side back to the server where PHP can then interact with the data.  Look up more info about client/server side languages and AJAX and you can get started.

Comment: That's not really correct. I had an alternate version where I made the value of `$ie8` = `2` in an `else` clause & PHP correctly output that value.

Answer (score 1):

Your results are obvious. In your PHP script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 8') != -1) {
    <?php $ie8 = 1; ?>
    alert(<?=$ie8?>);
}

</script>
```

When this is interpreted serverside, this is what the browser receives

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 8') != -1) {
    alert(1);
}

</script>
```

You are setting PHP variable inside javascript block. PHP is what gets interpreted first (before browser gets to interpret the javascript)..