# How to make a massege for IE6-IE8 to upgrade their browser?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, css, cross-browser

I've been working on a large website project, and I upgraded the website to html5 and css3, while the problem goes to supporting IE6-IE8 which needs a lot of hacks and debugging, using HTML5Shiv, CSS3pie, Modernizr Selectivizr and many other browser polyfills, which is a great deal of time.

And the fact of the huge count down of the usage percent of those versions of IE which is about 0.1%-IE6 0.6%-IE7 4.6%-IE8 which is all about 5.3% and the percentage is still going down.
In addition to the fact that soon Microsoft will drop down support for Windows XP on 2014, which is few months from now, sounds like a big waste of time and energy for such a huge project.

So like any web developer that want to provide the best environment experience for the audience I was Thinking and looking for the best way to provide IE6-IE8 users a way through a clean informative easy and convenience short way to show them a message that provides to download the latest version of other web browsers. So I've found this two JavaScript built solutions [ie6-upgrade-warning](http://code.google.com/p/ie6-upgrade-warning/) and [sevenup](http://code.google.com/p/sevenup/) on code.google.com that carry the same idea but both only targeted for IE6 only, and I'm quite a beginner in JavaScript.

Is there anyway to add this functionality to include IE7 & IE8 in the javaScript file of sevenup for example? or any other solutions for this purpose that I don't know of like a hosted JS widget I might be able to use to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I show a message to IE6/IE7 browsers to upgrade to IE8 and have IE8 not show the IE7 warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822508/how-can-i-show-a-message-to-ie6-ie7-browsers-to-upgrade-to-ie8-and-have-ie8-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create your own plugin like this

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<p>Sorry! You are running IE 8 or an earlier version of IE. <br>Please use IE 9 or greater</p>
<style>
     //Apply your own styles
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Once I did this, by fading the background and show designed div with the above message.